# Question on proof of $H_n(X) \cong \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A}H_n(X_\alpha)$ in introduction to topological manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, direct-sum

In the book introduction to topological manifolds by John M. Lee, we have the following proposition (p. 345):

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ the
>   set of path components of $X$. Then  $$H_n(X) \cong \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A}H_n(X_\alpha)$$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now the proof starts as follows: for all $\alpha \in A$, the inclusions $\iota_\alpha : X_\alpha \to X$ induce isomorphisms $$\bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} C_n(X_\alpha) \to C_n(X)$$
My question is, how exactly do they induce isomorphisms, or more generally a homomorphism?

Comment: What is your definition of $C_n(X)$ ?

Comment: Usually $C_n$ is just a formal sum of $n$-dimensional simplices.  Since simplices are connected, you can partition them by components of $X$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948726/why-is-the-homology-group-isomorphic-to-the-homology-groups-of-connected-compone?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, each $\iota_\alpha$ induces a homomorphism $C_n(X_\alpha)\to C_n(X)$.  Combining these homomorphisms together, we get a homomorphism $\bigoplus_\alpha C_n(X_\alpha)\to C_n(X)$.  Explicitly, an element of $\bigoplus_\alpha C_n(X_\alpha)$ has finitely many nonzero coordinates, each of which is a formal linear combination of maps $\Delta^n\to X_\alpha$ for different values of $\alpha$.  Given such an element, we compose all of these maps with the inclusion maps $X_\alpha\to X$ to get maps $\Delta^n\to X$.  So we have finitely many formal linear combinations of maps $\Delta^n\to X$, which we can just add together to get a single formal linear combination of maps $\Delta^n\to X$, i.e. an element of $C_n(X)$.

To see that this is an isomorphism, note that every map $\Delta^n\to X$ factors through $X_\alpha$ for exactly one $\alpha$ (since its image must be contained in a path-component of $X$).  So every element of $C_n(X)$ can uniquely be written as a sum of elements which come from $C_n(X_\alpha)$ for different values of $\alpha$: given a chain, just split it up into its simplices which are contained in the different path-components of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the cice answer. I wonder how can we proceed to get $H_n(X) \cong \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A}H_n(X_\alpha)$ ? My guess it is follows from here $H_n(X)= \frac{Z_n(X)}{B_n(X)} = \frac{\oplus Z_n(X_{\alpha})}{\oplus B_n(X_{\alpha})} = \oplus \frac{Z_n(X_{\alpha})}{B_n(X_{\alpha})}$ ?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric.